# how to schedule "pm2 start" script in ubuntu repeatedly?

Tags: python, ubuntu, background

So i have a python script running under pm2 in the background process.
The code is simply
`os.system("sudo python webhooks.py)` and the reason for this is that the webhooks.py file is meant to have port 80 opened to receive data which requires a sudo permission to run webhooks.py

and so the only way i've found using pm2 is to run the command as such.

But it seems that the pm2 process dies unexpectedly without showing any logs. I've checked all the log files and it just seems to die.

So, is there a way to run "pm2 restart all" command in intervals? say, every 1 hour?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `pm2` itself to solve this exact problem? I suggest you dig some more and find out _why_ your process is failing, and why it isn't generating any output. Fix _that issue_ instead of trying to work around it and tackle a symptom.

Comment: In any case, you're looking for `cron`. This isn't a programming issue (and is therefore off-topic). Search for "ubuntu cron" and go from there. If you need more info, try searching on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use crontab to schedule your script.

Example, if you want it to run every 10 mins do:

`crontab -e`

Then:

`*/10 * * * * python /{{your-path}}/{{your-script}}.py`

To check logs do:

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`